# BaseQuery class missing in new NEST dll version NEST.1.1.2

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

What is the replacement of BaseQuery class in new version.
I couldn't find it anywhere.

My problem is how to generate syntax in c# for the search criteria as:

```
public class TextSearch
{
   public string Headline {get;set;}
   public string Summary {get;set;}
}
```

I need to search using text 'you', against two column as OR operator, Column 1 summary and Column 2 headline.

Earlier I was doing,

```
                var orQuery = new List<BaseQuery>();

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchtext))
                {
                    orQuery .Add(Query<TextSearch>.Terms("headline", searchOptions.text.ToLower().Split(' ')));
                    orQuery .Add(Query<TextSearch>.Terms("summary", searchOptions.text.ToLower().Split(' ')));
                }
           var finalQuery = new List<BaseQuery>();

            finalQuery .Add(Query<TextSearch>.Bool(o => o.Should(orQuery.ToArray())));
```

Now this doesn't work.
Is there any better syntax for searching in new version.
The search criteria should using LIKE with OR, 
e.g. summary LIKE '%you%' OR headling LIKE '%you%'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The documentation on the breaking changes in NEST 1.0 is pretty complete:

http://nest.azurewebsites.net/breaking-changes.html

We renamed `BaseQuery` to `QueryContainer`

The query can be:

```
client.Search<TextSearch>(s=>s
    .Query(q=>
       q.Terms("headline", words)
       || q.Terms("summary", words)
    )
)
```

If `words` is empty or null that part is not rendered see the `conditionless query` section here:

http://nest.azurewebsites.net/nest/writing-queries.html

Comment: Would be nice if you could update the documentation online. Got caught by this one too (NEST newbie).

Comment: Sorry see sharper, we are revamping the docs making all the snippets in the documentation code we also compile which should hopefully catch mistakes like this in the future!

Answer (score 0):

@Martijn Laarman
Since we have numerous filter criteria that will be dynamic based on user selected filter,
I'm constructing Filter Query in amethod based on user slelcted filter and then pass it to Search<> method as:

```
 QueryContainer mainQuery = null; 
 if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchOptions.SearchText))
 {
   var headline = Query<T>.Terms("headline", searchOptions.Headline.ToLower());
   var summary = Query<T>.Terms("fullSummary", searchOptions.Summary.ToLower());
   mainQuery &= (headline || summary);
 }
 if (searchOptions.FromDate != DateTime.MinValue && searchOptions.ToDate != DateTime.MinValue)
 {
     var dateFilter = Query<T>.Range(
                                r => r.OnField("processedDate").GreaterOrEquals(searchOptions.FromDate, ElasticDateFormat).LowerOrEquals(searchOptions.ToDate, ElasticDateFormat));
     mainQuery &= dateFilter;
 }
 var result = Client.Search<T>(s => s.Query(mainQuery ).Size(Int32.MaxValue));
```

Here Client is a property that returns ElasticClient object.
Hope thats the correct way of doing.